# Why is my Mac Mini asking for the admin password even though it is set up for SmartCard + PIN

Tags: macos, authentication, smart-card

I have a Mac Mini, running Monterey, and am trying to install a new version of Visual Studio for mac. When I install the app, it asks for the admin password. I try to enter the password, but it says I need to authenticate using SmartCard Authentication. The Yubikey is currently inserted into the Mac Mini.

The login screen is asking for a PIN like it should be.The terminal also prompts for the pin instead of the password, but for some reason, the app installer is asking for the password instead. I have a profile installed to force Yubikey + PIN, so I don't know why it asks for the password instead of the PIN. I also see that the User preferences ask for a password instead of a PIN when I try to unlock it to make changes. Is there something I am missing to fully enable the Yubikey + PIN authentication for everything on the mac? I already created the user mappings and applied the profile to enforce Smartcard + PIN only.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!